# Variation problem for PDE: What solution space should I take?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

> > Consider the PDE
> >     $$
> > u_t=u_{xx}+\cos u-1+\mu.\qquad (1)
> > $$
> >     with $u\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, (t,x)\mapsto u(t,x)$.
> >
> > Does this PDE have a variational structure, i.e. can it be written as
> >     $$
> > u_t=-\delta \mathcal{E}(u)
> > $$
> >     for some integral functional $\mathcal{E}(u)$ and its first variation $\delta\mathcal{E}(u):=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{E(u+\varepsilon v)-E(u)}{\varepsilon}$? And which solution space is a good idea?

- Maybe solutions $u(t,\cdot)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ what was my first idea which I tried with the functional
  $$
  \mathcal{E}(u):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{2}(u_x)^2+F(u)\, dx,\qquad\text{ where }F'(u)=-\cos u+1-\mu.
  $$
  This gave me
  $$
  \langle \delta\mathcal{E}(u), v\rangle_{L^2}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_xv_x+F'(u)v\, dx.
  $$

Integrating by parts, I get
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_xv_x+F'(u)v\, dx=[u_x(s)v(s)]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}(-u_{xx}+F'(u))v\, dx.
$$
Now, I have to write this as some $L^2$-scalar product term but for this, I would need that the first summand on the right hand side vanishes, i.e.
$$
u_x(+\infty)v(+\infty)-u_x(-\infty)v(-\infty)=0\qquad (2)
$$ 
since then only the integral on the right hand side would remain and this is nothing else but $\langle -u_{xx}+F'(u),v\rangle_{L^2}$. Hence I would get
$$
\delta\mathcal{E}(u)=-u_{xx}+F'(u)
$$
and, consequently, $u_{t}=-\delta\mathcal{E}(u)$.

*Unfortunately, I think (2) does not have to be true or to make sense in general for $u(t,\cdot),v(t,\cdot)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.*

So, I think I have to use another space as $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with this result, there should be no harm in assuming $v$ is smooth with either compact support, or vanishing sufficiently fast. For instance, if you just want to show the $E(u(\cdot,t))$ is decreasing in $t$, then you only need to take $v = u_{xx} + \cos(u) - 1 + \mu$.

Comment: @Jeff I am not quite sure if I do understand what you mean. To my computations, I get $\frac{d}{dt}E(\cdot,t)=\int_R u_xu_{xt}+F'(u)u_t\, dx$. Integrating by parts, I get $\int_R u_xu_{xt}\, dx=[u_xu_t]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_R u_{xx}u_t\, dx$. Now, the question is again, whether $[u_xu_t]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=0$ (or not) in order to get (not to get) $\int_R u_xu_{xt}+F'(u)u_t\, dx=\int_R (-u_{xx}+F'(u))u_t\, dx=-\int_R u_t^2\, dx\leq 0$.

Comment: If you want functions that vanish at $\pm \infty$ and whose derivatives also vanish at $\pm \infty$, you might want to look at the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).